# Angular toSignal(toObservable()) does return undefined

Tags: angular, angular-signals

Hi assuming following code

```
import { Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { toObservable, toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

const result = toSignal(toObservable(signal(10)))
console.log(result()) // does log undefined instead of 10
```

I would assume that `result()` will return `10` instead of `undefined`.
However it seems like I'm missing something but I dunno what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect you're seeing is due to the current implementation of **[toObservable](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/dca6d6e0b870269c673fc4b98657f4e6699bda84/packages/core/rxjs-interop/src/to_observable.ts)**.  If you look at the implementation you'll see that the emissions are created inside of an **[effect](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects)**.  Effects always run asynchronously during the change detection cycle.  So you can't count on them running immediately.

If you think about it, this is the best that could be done.  For example, it could've performed an initial emission before the [watcher](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/dca6d6e0b870269c673fc4b98657f4e6699bda84/packages/core/rxjs-interop/src/to_observable.ts#L43) (`subject.next(source())`), but...

- Without any guards, the first execution of the effect would potentially cause a double emission of the same value.
- A *boolean* variable could've been created to skip the emission from the first execution of the effect, but there's no way of knowing if the source signal changed before that first effect ran.
- Instead of a *boolean*, the watcher could compare the current value with the source value and only emit changes, but maybe the the *equal* function on the signal was set to something that wanted repeated emissions, and now you're potentially omitting valid emissions.

So take it for granted that the first emission by an observable created from **toObservable** will be delayed.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `toSignal` has  `Signal<number | undefined>`

Before the Observable emits its first value, the Signal will return undefined

To avoid this, either an initialValue can be passed or the requireSync option enable

```
const result = toSignal(toObservable(signal(10)),{ initialValue: 10 })
console.log(result()) //logs intial value 10
```

[You can read More about here](https://netbasal.com/converting-observables-to-signals-in-angular-what-you-need-to-know-4f5474c765a0)

Comment: from my understanding the signal within `toObservable` should emit immediatly its value, therefor no intiialValue should be necessary. However if I try  const result = toSignal(toObservable(signal(10)),{ requireSync: true }) then Angular will throw an error that the Observable did not emit synchronously.

Comment: You can read about taht here:https://netbasal.com/converting-observables-to-signals-in-angular-what-you-need-to-know-4f5474c765a0#:~:text=When%20the%20toSignal%20function%20is%20called